# Is there any built-in function to draw rectangle on tracked objects?

Tags: c++, opencv

After some HSV correction, erosion and dilation using `trackbars`, contours are generated using

```
findContours(hsv, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

and then in a sequential loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    bound = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    if (bound.area() > 1000 && bound.area() < 2000)
        rectangle(cam, bound.tl(), bound.br(), color);
}
```

rectangles are drawn on screen.

Is there any built in function to do it in parallel or without using sequential loop?

Comment: No. What's the problem with the loop?

Comment: @Miki, Every operation before `for loop` was done by a single line instruction, ie. `read`, `cvtColor`, `inRange`, `erode`, `dilate`, `findContours`.  I thought there is something like `draw(rectangle, contours, size, color, thickness)` instead of `for`.

Comment: cv::rectangle is a single line, right? You can write your own drawResults function with any number of parameters and logic/semantic.

Comment: you can parallelize a loop easily with openmp, but be careful that rects could overlap and access the same memory in parallel

Comment: @Micka, thats right. SIMD, MPI and OpenMPs are for next month.

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend drawing multiple rectangles at the same time, since those drawing functions read/write to the same data array. So it is hard to parallelize, without running into race conditions. If you allow the drawing of multiple rectangles simultaneously, you need to make sure that they don't overlap, meaning access the same data (check their boundaries). That makes the solution ugly and hard to debug.

Comment: @julian59189, So, the sequential drawing will be faster than drawing using thread/mutex, right?

Comment: It depends how you use it. If you multithread it and lock the whole frame for every drawing operation, then it will definitely be slower since you create overhead but it will still be executed sequential. If you are smart with memory access you might be able to draw multiple rectangles simultaneously without locking the whole frame. It might still be slower, depending on the overhead you create to make it happen. In general you shouldn't draw on a frame if you care about efficient code.

Comment: @julian59189, only way I can think of, to be smart with memory access, is to split the array up to the number of threads I want to create

Comment: But you need a conditional lock or something like this. A way would be to split the image into four areas and have a mutex that you lock for each of them. E.g. 


`if(rect is in top left corner) lock_top_left_mutex`
If you don't lock the frame you will into race conditions. If you lock the whole frame for every rectangle you draw, then you will not gain any performance improvements.